# Can someone please help with asp.net configuration error?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have an issue that is driving me nuts and I have tried everything I can think of to solve it.

I started gettting the following error when I tried to launch asp.net configuration from within all visual studio pro 2008 projects and websites.

"Server Error in '/asp.netwebadminfiles' Application.
Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the \\ section in the application configuration."

I am not sure what I have changed to start getting this error.

The problem is not confined to a particular project as I started a basic project from scratch and get the same issue. I get the error on all projects and websites.

I can still run the projects from the local server without any problem.

I have done what the error suggests to no avail. Is there a setting somewhere I have inadvertently changed to get this problem?

Comment: Cunners, you can post your last comment as an answer and let people vote. Also easier to find for people with similar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just to close this off.

There is a backup of the machine.config and web.config files in the /CONFIG directory with _default on the end. I renamed the existing files to _old and copied the new files to machine.config and web.config and all is now good and the asp.net config launches as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at machine.config and \Windows\...\CONFIG\web.config and noted when they were last changed?

Comment: i suspect the last modified date is about the same time i started seeing this issue. is there any way to restore them to default?

Comment: just to close this off. there is a backup of the machine.config and web.config files in the /CONFIG directory with _default on the end. rename the existing files to _old and copy the new files to machine.config and web.config and all is now good. Thanks for the lead.